# Read paragraphs in order in PDFBox

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to parse a journal page using PDFBox. Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("myfile.pdf"))) {

    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

        PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

        PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        tStripper.setParagraphEnd("\n");

        String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);

        String output = "";

        String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            output += line + "\n";
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is, even though the paragraphs I get are ok, they show up in a completely random order. I need to get the paragraphs in natural order (top-bottom, left-right), but PDFBox seems to jump from one side of the page to the other for no real reason. My original PDF file also contains images at random positions, which I'm thinking might have something to do with this.

Here's a sample of the PDF that is not being read in order:

[image]

And here's what I get from that sample:

```
GALIZA>2-3
Analizamos os programas de PSOE, PP, 
En Común-Unidas Podemos e do BNG

> Na Galiza hai case 15 librarías por cada 
100.000 habitantes

> Só o 26% das persoas propietarias son 
mulleres, fronte ao 74% de homes 

A media de 
traballadoras dunha 
libraría e de 3,5

TRABALLO>15
Día das Librarías

As oito 
medidas 
electorais 
para Galiza
```

Is there a way to get the paragraphs in natural order?

Comment: It is difficult to comment about it without looking at the pdf.

Comment: Just added a sample

Comment: *"but PDFBox seems to jump from one side of the page to the other for no real reason"* - the reason is that the text drawing instructions in your specific PDF occur in that weird order, PDFBox merely reflects that to you...

Comment: That's what I was thinking, thanks for your answer. I'll have to find another way

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("myfile.pdf"));
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        for (int p = 0; p <= document.getNumberOfPages(); p++) {
            stripper.setStartPage(p);
            stripper.setEndPage(p);
            String text = stripper.getText(document);
            System.out.println(text);
        }
```

May be not using `PDFTextStripperByArea` which uses heuristics. Just getting text and then formatting it? Could you try this?

As I said in  comments, that it is difficult to assess without looking at pdf directly

Comment: Now it reads full lines of text, which doesn't work for me cause the journal I'm trying to parse is written in columns, so PDFBox is essentially mixing lines of different paragraphs that are at at the same y position

Comment: You could try ExtractTextByArea if you know the positions.

Comment: Thanks both for your comments. Unfortunately, the positions are unknown beforehand

Comment: I had a similar issue parsing some pdf files, and this solution solved my problem, thanks.
I would also suggest the use of the library/app tabula if still having problems. It could be use as command line application or as a java library with tabula-java: https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java